# Fancybox Image Swap

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

Hi is there  away to use Fancybox 2 as normal, so it has the image thumbs, but they swap a large image that is on the same page as the thumbs, but when you click on the main image, it opens it full size in a  lightbox?

If fancybox is not the right one for this, can someone recommend one for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

wrap the image with an anchor tag and give the full resolution image link in href and then initialize the colorbox

Sample HTML:

```
<a href="href for high res image">
    <img src="source of small image" />
</a>
```

initialize the script like

```
$("a").colorbox();
```

For live demo use this [link](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/).
For documents use this [link](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: I'm not sure how to code that, can you show me an example? I'm not sure how to pass the large image the full size image link so it opens up when the large image is clicked on. :(

Comment: I want to have a have a central image on the page though, that when the user clicks on one of the thumbs, it changes the central image, but when the user clicks on the central image, it opens the full image in a lightbox. Is that what you're thinking here?

Comment: i am afraid not. but still you can use this plugin for the lightbox.